# Converting dataframe to factor automatically

Tags: r

I am trying to remove duplicates

```
laa <-subset(la,select =c(PermID))

class(laa)

laa1<-laa[!duplicated(laa$userPermID), ]

class(laa1)
```

when i ran first two lines the class command is showing it as data.frame but after running the duplicate command it is converting into factor automatically. 
Is there any specific reason. Because iam not able to see it in dataframe

Comment: Most probably, it was already a `factor` when it was still in the data.frame. Use `str` instead of `class` for some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are only selecting the 'PermID' in the first step, the default option while subsetting the rows with `[` having a single column data.frame would be `drop=TRUE` resulting in a `vector` instead of a `data.frame`.  Assuming that 'PermID' is a `factor` column, the `class` of the `vector` will be `factor`.  To avoid that, use `drop=FALSE`.

```
laa1 <- laa[!duplicated(laa$userPermID), , drop=FALSE]
```

The `class(laa1)` would be `data.frame`.

---

If we look at the documentation `?"["`, the default usage is

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
>
> drop:  For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the
> lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for
> extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further
> details.